# Android - Parse.com Upload File issue

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have developed code to upload a file using the Android Parse API.

My code is below:

```
String name = "" + IMGname;
ParseFile file = new ParseFile(name.toLowerCase(), byteArray);
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("UserDetails_New");
gameScore.put("userName", "" + userName.getText().toString().toLowerCase());

gameScore.put("userPhotoProfile", file);

gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

My Problem is: The above code works most of the time but not every time. Sometimes it uploads the file and sometimes not. Can any one tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this using : `file.saveInBackground();`

it means we have to upload file first using below code:

```
byte[] data = "Working at Parse is great!".getBytes();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);
file.saveInBackground();
```

after the save completes, do below steps

```
ParseObject jobApplication = new ParseObject("JobApplication");
jobApplication.put("applicantName", "Joe Smith");
jobApplication.put("applicantResumeFile", file);
jobApplication.saveInBackground();
```

So, my answer is:

```
String name = "" + IMGname;
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile(name.toLowerCase(), byteArray);
                file.saveInBackground();

                ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("UserDetails_New");
                gameScore.put("userName", "" + userName.getText().toString().toLowerCase());

                gameScore.put("userPhotoProfile", file);

                gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

Instead of this try to listen for the result callback. So that you can figure out what is going wrong with the file save process.

```
gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
        if( arg0 != null )
        {
            //Handle Error here
        }
    }
});
```

You can also use `saveEventually` Method. The advantage with this method is that it will call try to update the Object when ever the network connection is back and also if you are closing your application in between a save process the Parse framework will hold this and will try to save the Object when ever the user returned back to the application.

Comment: your code does not help. i have already tried this..

Comment: I am not claiming it as a solution it is a hint to rectify what is going wrong at the server end from there you can figure out the error or the route cause... there is one more thing in Parse for a normal account the nof API request per second is 20 that also can be an issue. Still its an assumption.